# variable is defined in the Ionic

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have declared a variable in the constructor as below

```
constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    this.data = null;
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((datas: any) => {
      this.dbUrl = datas[0].db_url2;
      console.log(this.dbUrl) // <- this output
    })
  }
```

Here I can see my output as

> 987456321

But I declare the variable in the same class in a different method.

```
getDetails() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    console.log(this.dbUrl); // <- this output
    return this.http.get(this.dbUrl + 'details', { headers: headers})

  }
```

When I display the output It's displaying as `Undefined`. The `dbUrl` is a global variable. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: When are you calling `getDetails`? `http.get` is an asynchronous method so if you try to call `getDetails` before `http.get` has completed then `dbUrl` won't be ready yet.

Comment: The `getDetails()` function should wait for the `http.get()` to be completed.

Answer (score 1):

In your first part of code, you're making a HTTP call, and this call subscribes to an `Observable`, it means that it does not return a result immediatly (since this is a web request). It observes the `http.get` changes.

In your second part of code, you're logging `dbUrl`, but the execution of your code is faster than the time needed by your app to complete the request. So here is why `dbUrl` is not set in the second log :

**1)** `dbUrl` is not defined
**2)** You're calling the `http.get` function, which is waiting from the server 
**3)** You're calling `getDetails`, and you log `dbUrl`, which is null
**4)** You get a response from the server, and then you set `dbUrl`

Here is what you can do :

```
// Create a method to get the dbUrl. This functions will return a `promise`.
getUrl(){
    return new Promise<any>(
    function (resolve, reject) {
      this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((datas: any) => {
        this.dbUrl = datas[0].db_url2;
        resolve(this.dbUrl);
      }
}
```

And then, modify your `getDetails` method :

```
getDetails() {
    // If `this.dbUrl` has not been set yet
    if(this.dbUrl == undefined){
          this.getUrl()
          .then(url => {
            this.dbUrl = url;
            this.getDetails();
           })
          .catch(error => console.log(error))
        })
    }else{
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
        return this.http.get(this.dbUrl + 'details', { headers: headers})
    }
}
```

When you will call `getDetails`, if dbUrl is not ready yet, it will wait for its value and then recursively call `getDails`, and finally execute your request